# Deleting data from SQLite - function order in code - jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite

```
$(document).on("click", "#delete", function(event){

db.transaction(function(tx){


           tx.executeSql( 'DELETE FROM Table1');
           tx.executeSql( 'DELETE FROM Table2');
           tx.executeSql( 'DELETE FROM Table3');
           tx.executeSql( 'DELETE FROM Table4');
           tx.executeSql( 'DELETE FROM Table5');
           tx.executeSql( 'DELETE FROM Table6');
           tx.executeSql( 'DELETE FROM Table7');


           });
               relistData();

               });
}
```

As you can see, when the delete button is pressed, all the tables are emptied.  Thing is, the function relistData() is supposed to update the data on the screen (to make it go away after being deleted (basically refresh)) but the function is being executed before the tables have been emptied, so the page just stays the same without deleting the page data.  My question is, where do I put the relistData() function to occur after the DELETE FROM tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`transaction` takes three arguments: the body of the transaction, the error callback, and the success callback. Call the `relistData()` function from inside the success callback:

```
$(document).on("click", "#delete", function(event){
  db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql( 'DELETE FROM Table1');
    tx.executeSql( 'DELETE FROM Table2');
    tx.executeSql( 'DELETE FROM Table3');
    tx.executeSql( 'DELETE FROM Table4');
    tx.executeSql( 'DELETE FROM Table5');
    tx.executeSql( 'DELETE FROM Table6');
    tx.executeSql( 'DELETE FROM Table7');
  }, function() {
    // this function will be called if an error occurs in the transaction body
  }, function() {
    // this function will be called when the transaction finishes without errors
    relistData();
  });
}
```